# Какой тип ячейки в таблице Postgres лучше задать для числа 2629245.0000 (это сумма денег)?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, типы-данных

Собственно, вопрос вынесен в заголовок, искал сам ответ, нашел и рекомендации сделать `decimal`, и `float` еще ряд идей.

Не понял, что выбрать. Числа из интересующего столбца предоставляют собой, согласно документации: "Входящие остатки «итого», тыс. руб.". Это что-то финансовое.

Может быть, кто-то сталкивался и поможет советом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации есть специальный [денежный тип](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/datatype-money) `money` для этого. Хотя и `decimal` обычно тоже для денег подходит.

`float` обычно не рекомендуется для денег, поскольку он не гарантирует точность представления чисел и точность вычислений во всех позициях.